# Function to add marker to existing google map not getting called

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When I call the codeAddress function in initialize function it gets called but when it is somewhere else as in the below example it doesn't get called. What's the error?

```
var geocoder;

var map;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
codeAddress();
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens so, because your map is initialized after the window is fully loaded where as codeAddress is executed immediately when window starts loading. Add an alert in codeAddress and you will figure it out by yourself. Also, any manipulation to the map should me done when map is properly initialized. To do so please use map idle listener to call codeAddress.

Answer (score 0):

The `codeAddress` function requires that the `initialize` function was executed before because in `codeAddress` you're referencing the global variable `map` which is initialized in `initialize`.

The line

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

registers `initialize` as a callback that gets executed as soon as the DOM has loaded. But when you call `codeAddress();` on the next line, the DOM might not have been loaded yet and, hence, `initialize` might not have been executed yet.

Therefore, calling `codeAddress` will work inside `initialize` but not in your example.